# Not able to start Form recognizer container

Tags: docker, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to run Form Recognizer Container, with the following command:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 --memory 4g --cpus 1 \
--mount type=bind,source=c:\input,target=/input  \
--mount type=bind,source=c:\output,target=/output \
containerpreview.azurecr.io/microsoft/cognitive-services-form-recognizer \
Eula=accept \
Billing={FORM_RECOGNIZER_ENDPOINT_URI} \
ApiKey={FORM_RECOGNIZER_API_KEY}
FormRecognizer:ComputerVisionApiKey={COMPUTER_VISION_API_KEY} \
FormRecognizer:ComputerVisionEndpointUri={COMPUTER_VISION_ENDPOINT_URI}
```

But I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Failed to inspect container 2c85b0a5b1b207c695f140b3b74ea6046c940b99f62e6b86330598848e978ebf: Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l: invalid argument.
time="2019-08-08T14:01:31+02:00" level=error msg="error waiting for container: context canceled"
```

Any hints or ideas?

Windows 10 and most recent Docker version.

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect your post command, it seems that you just easily copy the same command from the offical document [`Install and run Form Recognizer containers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/form-recognizer-container-howto#form-recognizer-1) and not to replace these arguments like `{FORM_RECOGNIZER_ENDPOINT_URI}` with your correct information. So the error message is

> Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l: **invalid argument**

If not as what I said above,  may you can get the useful issue fix solution from the same GitHub issue on MacOS https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-operator/issues/674.